# How do I change a value only when a key is pressed down?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, while-loop, keypress

I have tried to make a code where a ball only moves when I press the arrow keys and when I let go it stops, but it continues to move. How can I fix this?

This is the part of the code that I have written:

```
document.onkeydown = function tast (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 39) {  // høyre
        høyre = 1;  
    } else {
        høyre = 0;
        console.log("ikke høyre")
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 37) {  // venstre
        venstre = 1;  
    } else {
        venstre = 0;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 38) {  // opp 
        opp = 1; 
    } else {
        opp = 0;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 40) {  // ned
        ned = 1;              
    } else {
        ned = 0;
    }
}

if (venstre == 1){
    kuler[0].x -= 4;
}
if (høyre == 1){
    kuler[0].x += 4;;
}
if (opp == 1){
    kuler[0].y -= 4;
}
if (ned == 1){
    kuler[0].y += 4;
}
```

Comment: It seems you have forgotten to take into account onkeyup.

Comment: the ting i that i only want it to move when the key is down

Comment: set it to move when the key is down. And make it stop moving when the key is up.... I think the answer below gives a good example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other then setting your values to `0` on `else`. Use a `onkeyup` event handler. Then for `onkeypress` set your values to `1`. And `onkeyup` set them to `0`:

```
document.onkeydown = function tast (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 39) høyre = 1;  
    if (e.keyCode == 37) venstre = 1;  
    if (e.keyCode == 38) opp = 1; 
    if (e.keyCode == 40) ned = 1;              
}

document.onkeyup = function tast2 (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 39) høyre = 0;  
    if (e.keyCode == 37) venstre = 0;  
    if (e.keyCode == 38) opp = 0; 
    if (e.keyCode == 40) ned = 0;              
}
```

Comment: Keyup should probably just set ALL the variables to 0.

Comment: @Barmar You can press more than a single key at a time. For example I could hold down both *left* and *up*, when I release *up* and keep *left* pressed, I should not stop, but go *left*. That why you don't want to set them all to 0.